# Find the minimum of $a^4+2b^4+3c^4$

Tags: inequality

Suppose  that $a, b,$ and $c$
are positive real numbers satisfying
$a+b+c=3$. Find the minimum of $$a^4+2b^4+3c^4$$

We know $f(x)=x^4$ is convex on the positive reals so by Jensen's Inequality, we have $$a^4+b^4+c^4\ge \frac{1}{27}$$
Hence $$a^4+2b^4+3c^4\ge \frac{1}{27}+b^4+2c^4$$
What now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure):
$$\left(a^4+2b^4+3c^4\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt[3]2}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]3}\right)^3 \geqslant (a+b+c)^4=3^4$$

Equality is possible when $a^3:b^3:c^3 =1:\frac12:\frac13$, so this gives the minimum.

Comment: The second term in the LHS seems like it came out of nowhere?

Comment: The second term is specifically chosen to "cancel" the coefficients of the first term - as you want in the RHS all terms with the same coefficient.  You can do the same proof with AM-GM also, by carefully selecting term by term the right coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

In fact if you use Lagrange multipliers you get:

$\vec{\nabla}(a^4+2b^4+3c^4)=(4a^3,8b^3,12c^3)\ \ \propto\ \ \vec{\nabla}(a+b+c-3)=(1,1,1)$ which gives
$$a^3=2b^3=3c^3$$
same as Macavity $a^3:b^3:c^3=1:\frac 12:\frac 13$ ratio presentation.

Since $x\mapsto x^3\ $ bijective this is also $\ a=\sqrt[3]{2}\,b=\sqrt[3]{3}\,c\ $ and the sum becomes $$a+b+c=\Big(1+\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{2}}+\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{3}}\Big)\,a=3$$

which reveal the origin of this second LHS term you were asking about.